# Using blur filter with nativecss component with xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, css, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nativecss

I'm using nativecss Xamarin component for an iOS application I'm working on. It's really great but the other day I wanted to use this css:

```
img{
      filter: blur(5px);
}
```

but It doesn't make any changes. other css styles like border or style guide works correctly. Is this because blur and some other effects work just on HTML5 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The webklit filter for that is vendor-prefixed. Try this instead:

```
img{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to hear. It seems to be a problem with the framework then. It does work in iOS 7+ devices, according to this tutorial: http://fonicmonkey.net/2013/06/03/blur-this-demonstrating-mobilesafaris-awesome-css3-filter-effects-support/